# is it ok send password in plain text to server side for doing authentication? What are common ways to avoid such plain text transfer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, cryptography, password-encryption

Is password gets transferred as plain text to server side when submit from client. am using asp.net mvc
I can generate authentication token once verified.

Comment: Your server should use HTTPS

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: You can send password in form of plain text but should be passed through Post method

Comment: There are authentication protocols (e.g., _password authenticated key exchange_, _verifiable random functions_) that don't require the server to know the client's password.  However, these protocols are not as widely deployed as the practice of having a server hash a password after sending it to that server through a secure channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it's not ok.

HTTPS will work as long as you are sending the password in the body or header, via a POST request, but it does nothing to protect it when you put sensitive information in the URL.

So, use POST, put the sensitive data in the body or header, not URL and finally issue the request over https.

Comment: The path and parameters of the URL are protected by SSL too. They are only sent when the connection has been stablished. But the URL can be cached by browser or proxies so it is not recommended to encode sensitive parameters